# Difference between software design and modeling and software analysis

Tags: uml, modeling, software-design

What is the basic difference between : modeling - software design and Software analysis .

Comment: This feels mega broad.  It might not fit on *any* SE site.

Comment: Design: create something new. Analysis: look into something old.

Comment: @JimJeffries - This likely wouldn't fare very well at Programmers either.  It's a mix of Too Broad and Unclear What You're Asking.  Please see: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/what-goes-on-programmers-se-a-guide-for-stack-overflow

Comment: If it is a question from quiz then it's really too broad and you'll have to try to answer it using your own facts/thoughts/words, [Wikipedia: Requirements analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirements_analysis), [Wikipedia: Software design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design) can be useful (as always). If it's unclear terms you've found while reading a book, then quote some more paragraphs from the book so that we can judge and explain the intended meaning by the context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Software analysis is the step which we analyse the software and create the use case diagram, and the software design is the preparation to the coding step, it contains class diagram and others, it is prepared from the requirement specifications and it helps in specifying hardware and system requirements and also helps in defining overall system architecture, there are following six phases in every software development life cycle model

1. Requirement gathering and analysis
2. Design
3. Implementation or coding
4. Testing
5. Deployment
6. Maintenance

Answer (score 1):

Software design is not about making diagrams. Software design is about the improving of flexibility and reusability of code. Diagrams are used just to model in a high level the good code that is "well-designed".

The following extract can clarify a little bit the misunderstood meaning of "Software design":

> "[...]When you are programming, you are doing detailed design. The manufacturing team for software is your compiler or interpreter. The source is the only complete specification of what the software will do. The cute boxes in class diagrams are not the design, they are a high level view of the design."

See [What is Software Design?](http://wiki.c2.com/?WhatIsSoftwareDesign)